# Migrations with South (Django 1.6 + MySQL) on Existing project

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

I need a tip on following situation

I've downloaded project with apps models, fixtures, migrations etc to local machine. Then created virtual env and made pip install -r requirements. Everything is ok.

Now I want to create tables in mysql using existing South migrations, but there is no south_migrationhistory table in database. Actually database only has django tables from ./manage.py syncdb

Should I use existing migration files or I have to delete them and create from scratch?

Comment: `./manage.py migrate ` should solve the problem

Comment: chuck the south migrations and do a syncdb!